# How to replace each letters in multiple words

Tags: python, letter

I have an array like this :

```
input =  ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" "thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"]
```

i would like output = `["thirty", "forty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]`

```
import re 
chaine = ["thirtheen", "fourteen", "fifteen"] 
print re.sub(r'[een]', 'y', ' '.join(chaine))
```

I try a lot of method (replace .. )  but i am stuck :/

Comment: Have you had a go with the method? Show us your attempts. Also what language are you using?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. would you like `one -> ony` and `four -> for` ?

Comment: I use python language, i edit my attempt.

Comment: no just thirteen -> thirty and fourteen -> forty :)

Comment: please ... I have really try :/

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for this. A simple `' '.join(chaine).replace('een', 'y')` does the job. Your regex `[een]` matches exactly one of e or n.

Comment: @jasper , yes but i would like something like : chaine = ["thirtheen", "fourteen", "fifteen"] 
print ' '.join(chaine).replace('een', 'y', 'our', 'o')

Comment: Then please update your answer to state exactly what output you want from which input you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you.

```
chain = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"] 


new_chain = []

for _ in chain:
    if _ == "fourteen":
        new_chain.append("forty")
    elif str.endswith(_,"een"):
        new_chain.append(_[:-3]+"y")
print new_chain
```

OUTPUT:

```
['thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety']
```

Comment: use `str.endswith()` instead of `[-3:]`

Comment: Thank you, just edited. Your suggestion was helpful. Upvoted your comment.

Comment: @newuser. You may tick mark my solution, if you find it useful. Thanks

Comment: Your response is useful but i wait other solutions ^^